# Is it possible to recover emails sent from SMTP?

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail, wordpress

So basically I have a contact form on my site. I just realized that the contact form didn't forward responses to my email because I didn't have `sendmail` installed.

Is there any way for me to recover the messages that got sent nowhere before I had `sendmail` installed?

In case you need to know, the contact form was made with a wordpress plugin called 'Contact Form 7'. Unfortunately that plugin doesn't record responses to a database.

Answer (score 1):

```
Unfortunately that plugin doesn't record responses to a database.
```

This pretty much sums is up.

My only suggestion would to be to check out your log files. If your application tried to execute this command and failed, there may be some information in the error print out that arose each time the method failed to execute.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for me to recover the messages that got sent nowhere before I had sendmail installed?

Yes, if the plugin committed them to a database before attempting to pass them to an MTA.

> Unfortunately that plugin doesn't record responses to a database.

ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Darn:( I was hoping there was some magical log that records all of the attempted emails. Oh well.

Comment: @exoro It's entirely up to the application layer at that point. If it attempts to send, and then discards an attempt after a failure, then there's nothing in the logs to recover. I've used contact forms in Wordpress before, and usually they store them in the database, so I'm a little surprised there's no trace.